# HTML5 - Section inside article

Tags: html

I know that every `<section>` must contain an `<h1>`, but if I put a `<section>` inside an `<article>`, what do I have to use inside the `<section>`? `<h1>` or `<h2>`?

In detail, my article is a blog entry, and the section is the "related content of the article", like a video or a set of images (gallery).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A section doesn't necessarily contain an `<h1>`, though they certainly help arrange your content and give it semantic meaning.

If I had the structure you are describing, I would certainly use the normal `<h1>-<h6>` progression to structure my document:

```
<article>
    <h1>...</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <section id="related-content">
        <h1>Related Content<h1>
        <h2>Video</h2>
        <p>...</p>
        <h2>Gallery</h2>
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
    <section id="another-section">
        <h1>Another amazing section!<h1>
        <h2>...</h2>
        <p>...</p>
        <h2>...</h2>
    </section>
</article>
```

As always, when in doubt, **validate your markup**: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

Why would your section require a `<h1>`? It doesn't.

If you put a `<section>` in an `<article>`, you can use any [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#flow-content) in your `<section>`, i.e. you can use both `<h1>` and `<h2>` as you like.